# nsq cannot consume message by connecting to nsqlookupd

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, nsq, go-nsq

I tried to use docker-compose to run nsq, the `docker-compose.yml` as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4160:4160"
      - "4161:4161"
  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4150:4150"
      - "4151:4151"
  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4171:4171"
```

I am using the nsq client [go-nsq](https://github.com/nsqio/go-nsq) to produce and consume messages, the messages can be consumed by connecting to nsqd directly, but cannot be consumed by connecting to nsqlookupd:

```
consumer.ConnectToNSQD("127.0.0.1:4150")  # success (output the consumed messages)

consumer.ConnectToNSQLookupd("127.0.0.1:4161")   # failed

2018/01/31 16:39:12 ERR    1 [test/liu] (967fcc2c88ae:4150) error connecting to nsqd - dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

I can connect to nsqlookup instance:

```
➜  test_nsq curl http://127.0.0.1:4161/ping
OK%
➜  test_nsq curl http://127.0.0.1:4161/nodes
{"producers":[{"remote_address":"172.22.0.3:59988","hostname":"967fcc2c88ae","broadcast_address":"967fcc2c88ae","tcp_port":4150,"http_port":4151,"version":"1.0.0-compat","tombstones":[false],"topics":["test"]}]}%
```

the source code link:

https://gist.github.com/liuzxc/1baf85cff7db8dee8c26b8707fc48799

Env:

```
OS: Mac EI Capitan 10.11.6
go version: 1.9.2
nsq: 1.0.0-compat(latest)
```

Any idea for this?

Comment: `consumer.ConnectToNSQLookupd` returns an error, can you provide it?

Comment: @leafbebop I print the go-nsq error msg, please look my update

Comment: I found the solution, should set -broadcast-address=127.0.0.1 for nsqd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I output the go-nsq log, then find the root cause, should add `-broadcast-address=127.0.0.1` for nsqd command, if not，nsqd will register its hostname to nsqlookupd, it cannot be resolved by client.