# NSQ cannot get the message

Tags: nsq

I look this:[nsq cannot consume message by connecting to nsqlookupd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536963/nsq-cannot-consume-message-by-connecting-to-nsqlookupd)

But he doesn't apply to me,All sorts of ways have been tried.It could be the environment.

system: VMware CentOS + Docker-compose  NSQ
Version: all latest

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4160:4160"
      - "4161:4161"
  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4150:4150"
      - "4151:4151"
  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4171:4171"
```

I tried adding -broadcast-address=127.0.0.1 in NSQD command but it would cause an admins page error.

docker-compose config

```
services:
  nsqadmin:
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
    depends_on:
    - nsqlookupd
    image: nsqio/nsq
    ports:
    - 4171:4171/tcp
  nsqd:
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160 -broadcast-address=127.0.0.1
    depends_on:
    - nsqlookupd
    image: nsqio/nsq
    ports:
    - 4150:4150/tcp
    - 4151:4151/tcp
  nsqlookupd:
    command: /nsqlookupd
    image: nsqio/nsq
    ports:
    - 4160:4160/tcp
    - 4161:4161/tcp
version: '3.0'
```

[image]

I hope you understand what I mean，After all, my English is poor
Any idea for this?

```
func Producer() {
    producer, err := nsq.NewProducer("192.168.132.128:4150", nsq.NewConfig())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("NewProducer", err)
        panic(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        if err := producer.Publish("test", []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Hello World "))); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Publish", err)
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

this code is successful He can add messages to nsqd,but I can’t connecting to nsqd

look this:

```
2019/07/05 14:19:00 INF    2 [test/testq] querying nsqlookupd http://192.168.132.128:4161/lookup?topic=test
2019/07/05 14:19:00 INF    2 [test/testq] (60366475943f:4150) connecting to nsqd
2019/07/05 14:19:01 ERR    2 [test/testq] (60366475943f:4150) error connecting to nsqd - dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

and this

```
{"channels":["testq"],"producers":[{"remote_address":"172.19.0.2:57250","hostname":"60366475943f","broadcast_address":"60366475943f","tcp_port":4150,"http_port":4151,"version":"1.1.0"}]}
```

I think the problem arises in the lookup connection NSQ But I don't know how to deal with him.

Answer (score 1):

i think you forgot something. Have you add this into your /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 nsqd
```

It allow your machine to recognize the local network with nsq network on docker. Hope this can help you. CMIIW.

Comment: I did the above and did not work for this reason

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add as per below,

```
--broadcast-address=nsqd
```

So your docker compose should be like below,

```
nsqd:
  command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160 --broadcast-address=nsqd
  depends_on:
  - nsqlookupd
  image: nsqio/nsq
  ports:
  - 4150:4150/tcp
  - 4151:4151/tcp
```

It should be working now

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a network problem, this may not be the best solution for something different from local env, but this works great for me in testing process:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqlookupd
    network_mode: host

  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=localhost:4160 # nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    network_mode: host

  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=localhost:4161 # nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    network_mode: host
  
  nsqfiles:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsq_to_file --lookupd-http-address=localhost:4161 --topic=testing --output-dir=/tmp/nsq/logs
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - messages-queue:/tmp/nsq/logs

volumes:
  messages-queue:
    driver: local
```